# Perform Paged Search in AD with total_size returned always 0 (Java)

Tags: java, search, active-directory, jndi, ldap-query

I'm doing paged search in AD with Java. As explained here [[Paged Results Control, Oracle]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/paged-results.html),

`total = prrc.getResultSize();` indicates the total entries in search result.

I wrote my code referencing from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JNDI-LDAP/howapagedsearchcanbeperformedusingthePagedResultsControlAPI.htm (sorry I couldn't add more than 2 links), I set the pageSize to 100, and I could retrieve more than 7000 entries (I set a counter). It always gives the following output

`***************** END-OF-PAGE "+ "(total: unknown) ***************`

that is, the case of `total==0`. I also print the value and it is indeed always 0. According to the documentation (the Oracle documentation of Paged Results Control, the first link), shouldn't it be the total number of results, 7000+?

Can anyone tell me why? I just want a nice printing result.

Comment: It is up to the LDAP server to implement it. AD might not be doing it and hence returns 0.

Comment: @Roshith Thanks. Maybe. [Paging Search Results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367011(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't mention anything about the total number of search result, only a cookie for retrieving the next page.   Apart from returning large result set, paged search is also intended to tear apart the search operations on the server so that it's not too heavy when there are many clients sending search requests. If the server could give a total number of searching results at the first page, it must have done a thorough search already, which doesn't apply the convenience.